# Populate a HashMap with all the entries stored in a .properties file

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

How do I populate my `HashMap` with all the entries stored in a separate `.properties` file ?
I have a file `resume.properties` placed along with the `class` files in the bin folder in Eclipse.

The file consists of entries like this

```
available = 1
bismarck = 1
employees = 1
reports = 1
home = 1
company = 1
work = 2
........
```

I want this entries to be populated into my HashMap as soon as the constructor of that class is invoked.

```
public class TextClassifier {

  static HashMap<String,Integer> resume = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public TextClassifier(){
    try {
      properties.load(TextClassifier.class.getResourceAsStream("resume.properties"));              
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
      String value = properties.getProperty(key);
      resume.put(key, Integer.valueOf(value));
    }

  }

  public static void printHashmap(HashMap<String,Integer> map){
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
      int val=entry.getValue();
      String key=entry.getKey();
      System.out.println(key + " = " + val);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    new TextClassifier();
    TextClassifier.printHashmap(TextClassifier.resume);

  }
}
```

But when I print the entries using the printAll method and match them with those in the actaul file, I do not find them matching. THere are entries which are printed which are not there in the file !!

I am populatin many HashMaps (which I have not shown) and so maybe entries from other files are getting printed. Where is the error ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, and also give us more representative code. For example, you've got a `static` variable here - we don't know whether you're reusing that when loading multiple maps.

Comment: `Properties` is _already_ a map (well, a `HashTable`).  Why can't you use it as-is?

Comment: Stop completely ignoring exceptions by catching them and doing nothing in the catch block, and you'll probably understand what's wrong, and concentrate on the part that needs a fix

Comment: If multiple threads are using the method `printHashmap` then declare the method as `synchronized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading a different resume.properties file to the one you think you are loafing.

Check the resource path for other files named resume.properties to figure it out.

You can also load directly from a file to force the use of a particular file by using an absolute path:

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/some/path/resume.properties");
```

---

The other possibility is that `properties` is a static variable that is being used elsewhere, and since the `load()` method doesn't clear existing values - it merely adds properties - you are seeing values previously loaded values somewhere else.